# How do I debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on destructInstance?

Tags: ios, crash

I am running the app on an iDevice and I get this error consistently:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance:
0x195b1bedc:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!
0x195b1bee0:  stp    fp, lr, [sp, #16]
0x195b1bee4:  add    fp, sp, #16
0x195b1bee8:  mov    x19, x0
0x195b1beec:  cbz    x19, 0x195b1bf64          ; objc_destructInstance + 136
0x195b1bef0:  ldr    x8, [x19]
0x195b1bef4:  and    x9, x8, #0x1
0x195b1bef8:  tbz    w8, #0, 0x195b1bf04       ; objc_destructInstance + 40
0x195b1befc:  ubfm   x10, x8, #2, #2
0x195b1bf00:  b      0x195b1bf14               ; objc_destructInstance + 56
0x195b1bf04:  ldr    x10, [x8, #32]    <-------- EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I am using ARC, so I would think I don't have to manage the various retain/deallocs. The thread view doesn't help me, other than showing me it's coming from AVFoundation.

Comment: Monitor the resource that interact with `AVFoundation` library and log there retain counts. Observe exactly in which condition this happens.

Comment: Can you post the full, symbolicated stack trace?

Comment: @AaronBrager I already learnt a new thing from your question :)

Comment: @neverhopeless I will check out how to do that, thanks.

Comment: @AaronBrager it seems symbolication is for apps that are in production and for when you get crash reports from iTunes Connect, but I am in Xcode in dev and debug mode, shouldn't the stack trace be symbolicated already?

Comment: ohhhh I just discovered that I can download the crash from the phone log from the Devices window... sorry, still newbie!

Comment: but that still doesn't explain why XCode doesn't write the symbols